# Azure storage container is showing "Network request failed - cannot access storage endpoint" when i tried to open the container

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-container-service

I am trying to learn azure DB on my own and trying to understand its services, recently I am stuck with this problem, and any help on this is much appreciated. I created a storage account with all default settings, and created a container called "Demo" with public Access level set to " Private (no anonymous access)". I can see the container "Demo" in containers, and when I try to open the container, it is showing me a pop-up message " Unable to load data " and in the background, it says " Network request failed - cannot access storage endpoint ". Can anyone please help me solve this? thank you.

[image]

When I tried to run a check, it gave me this information about the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**I tried in my environment and I got the same error:**

**Error:**

[image]

This error occurs due to any blockage in **`proxy servers`** .

> Note: If your using a proxy server, kindly allow the storage account blob URL on your proxy server to establish access.

When I tried to access the azure account blob URL using proxy which is not allowed by the URL and I'm getting the above error.

For testing, I disabled the proxy server in my local environment and it works as expected also I can see my files in my container.

**Portal:**
[image]

**Reference:**

- [Allow the Azure portal URLs on your firewall or proxy server - Azure portal | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/azure-portal-safelist-urls?tabs=public-cloud)
  you can refer to this document to add the URL to the proxy server.

Comment: Thank you for the info Venkatesan. Cheers!