# Network request failed - cannot access storage endpoint (Blob Storage) in Azure

Tags: azure, containers, blob, storage

There is Gen 2 storage account and it has been setup to access publicly with "Enable from all network". But still I am getting "Network request failed -  cannot access storage endpoint" error when I try to access containers. It used to work before but suddenly I get the error message now and not able to access any containers in that storage account. Can you any please help?

Comment: Could you provide error and more in detail?

Comment: Error message is:  Network request failed- cannot access storage endpoint. Details: Your firewall settings may be preventing network access from this client to the storage data endpoint. CORS settings on your storage accounts may be preventing network access form this client.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75823167/azure-storage-container-is-showing-network-request-failed-cannot-access-stora/75831004#75831004

Comment: How can I find out if IT has proxy server setup that is blocking the access? Is there a way i can test it myself with out involving IT support?

Answer (score 0):

> Network request failed - cannot access storage endpoint (Blob Storage) in Azure

In my environment, I got the same error.

[image]

The above error occurs when It seems like you are facing an issue with accessing the storage endpoint.

The error message indicates that your firewall configurations could be preventing this client from reaching the storage data endpoint around the network. Additionally, this client may not be able to access the network due to CORS settings on your storage accounts.

Also, check with proxy servers in your local environment if the proxy servers are setup with the correct port and address.

[image]

I tried with disabled both the proxy server and firewall in my local environment and it works as expected also I can see my files in my ADLS gen2 storage container.

**Portal:**

[image]

**Reference:**

[Allow the Azure portal URLs on your firewall or proxy server - Azure portal | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/azure-portal-safelist-urls?tabs=public-cloud)